# WooCommerce product variation with the REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, dokan

i want create a new product with woocoommerce API, i have a color attribute and size attribute. when i try to test the response is:

```
    {
    "code": "rest_invalid_json",
    "message": "Invalid JSON body passed.",
    "data": {
        "status": 400,
        "json_error_code": 4,
        "json_error_message": "Syntax error"
    }
}
```

for the endpoint i use is POST {{site_url}}/wp-json/wc/v3/products/1234/variations/batch and for request body testing is

```
{
     "name": "bandana ricardo milos",
     "type": "12345",
     "regular_price": "15.000",
     "description": "bandana sejuta umat",
     "images":{
        // 
                    "src": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a4/0b/01/a40b01172b2f751fef7bcd2294af9dfd.jpg",
                    "position": 0
     }
```

can someone help me to fix this issue, thanks

Comment: Unable to see attributes in your Body data. and as you're using the batch method, your data format should be in batch format, you can see the format on WooCommerce documentation https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#batch-update-product-variations

Comment: Do you actually have that `// ` in your JSON? That would invalidate it. (And what you have shown, is also missing a closing `}`.)